# Build and publish C# .NET Web App via command line

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web, publish

I need to be able to generically and separately build and publish C# ASP.NET Web Applications. Ideally, I would like to use MSBuild to build the application, and if that succeeds, I would like to simply publish the site preferably solely with file copy.

Currently, I am able to build web application quite easily with MSBuild, but it is the publishing that is causing confusion. After the build, the binaries sit in the bin folder, but I am not sure what files to copy. What would be a good way to mimic the operations that VS's publish feature does, and still keeping everything generic?

Comment: Any deployment task is just wrapped in MSBuild arguments.

Comment: With .NET CORE 3.0 this is simplified, Checkout this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56710981/6441150

Answer (score 27):

You can invoke the Visual Studio web publish pipeline using the command line, check out this tutorial it shows you step by step how to do it:

### Specifying the publish profile

You can specify the publish profile by name or by the full path to the .pubxml file, as shown in the following example:

```
msbuild C:\ContosoUniversity\ContosoUniversity.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=C:\ContosoUniversity\ContosoUniversity\Properties\PublishProfiles\Test.pubxml
```

### Web publish methods supported for command-line publishing

Three publish methods are supported for command line publishing:

- MSDeploy - Publish by using Web Deploy.
- Package - Publish by creating a Web Deploy Package. You have to install the package separately from the MSBuild command that creates it.
- FileSystem - Publish by copying files to a specified folder.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/command-line-deployment

Comment: thank you! I was thinking about doing that but would ideally prefer something simpler like file copy, or would it then not be possible to keep it generic?

Comment: You can create a FileSystem publish profile and then use the PublishProfile switch the article shows how to do this.  Look towards the bottom of the article.

Comment: I followed the tutorial's instructions for building a project and the publish didn't work.

Comment: I would start a new question since this is 3 years old.

Answer (score 0):

The latest projects can be built by:

```
dotnet build MyWebsite.sln
```

For more info please refer the microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build

**Note:** Old ASP.NET projects are not supported. Please use MsBuild instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/24063993/1143349.