# Publish .NET Core App As Portable Executable

Tags: c#, .net-core, publish, portable-executable, self-contained

I have a simple .net core app and publish it by following command:

```
 dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x64
```

**SqlLocalDbStarter.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Win32.Registry" Version="4.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

When publish process finished dotnet create `win10-x64` folder at `bin\Release` folder then after open it the folder contains `publish` folder and some dll and exe files.

There are some issue for me:

- Which one of `exe` files (inside / outside publish folder) i need to PE app?
- Why when i cut `exe` file and move it in other place it doesn't run (without message)?
- If I need all of `dll` files to run application, so there are tow options for me (inside / outside publish folder), inside publish folder size is 66 MB but outside publish folder is 1 MB.
- I want to have a one `exe` file to run my program without dll files.

[image: Folder Size Image]

Comment: Single EXE is not supported yet - it is planned for .NET Core 3.0: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/05/07/net-core-3-and-support-for-windows-desktop-applications/

`For cases where the maximum isolation is required, you can deploy .NET Core with your application. We’re working on new build tools that will bundle your app and .NET Core together as in a single executable, as a new option.`

Comment: thanks @karelzikmund, great answer. is there issue in github for this ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### .NET Core 3.0

.NET Core 3.0 supports it out of the box. It packs all stuff in one `.exe` file (~68 MB for a basic console app). There is [`PublishTrimmed=true`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-0-preview-6/) option that can decrease size to ~28 MB by analyzing static code references and excluding unused framework assemblies from the final build.

To configure `single exe` build edit your `csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**or** on the command line in a folder with `csproj` file:

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true
```

For more details see a great answer given by Gopi.

### Standalone utils

[`Warp`](https://github.com/dgiagio/warp) (thanks to Darien Shannon for mentioning it in the comment) and [`dotnet CoreRT`](https://github.com/dotnet/corert). Both work with previous versions of .Net Core also

#### [Warp](https://github.com/dgiagio/warp)

It is a tool similar to [ILMerge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17630) for the classic `.NET Framework`. It is very easy to use. For the basic console app, It can produce `.exe` ~35 MB without tree shaker and around 10-15 MB with tree shaker.

#### [Dotnet CoreRT](https://github.com/dotnet/corert)

As of Jan 2022 this project is superseded by [NativeAOT](https://github.com/dotnet/runtimelab/tree/feature/NativeAOT) experiment in dotnet/runtimelab repo. Thanks to @t.j.

For now, you can try to pre-compile the application into a native single-file executable using [`dotnet CoreRT`](https://github.com/dotnet/corert) project. I'm saying "try" because documentation [says](https://github.com/dotnet/corert/tree/master/Documentation):

> This project is in the early stages of its development.

Nevertheless, it works at least for simple applications. See the sample [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corert/tree/master/samples/HelloWorld).
According to its description, you need to run the following command in the project folder:

```
dotnet new nuget
```

> This will add a nuget.config file to your application. Open the file
> and in the  element under  add the following:

```
<add key="dotnet-core" value="https://dotnet.myget.org/F/dotnet-core/api/v3/index.json" />
<add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
```

Then run this:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.DotNet.ILCompiler -v 1.0.0-alpha-*
```

Then run this:

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c release
```

> Once completed, you can find the native executable in the root folder
> of your project under /bin/x64//netcoreapp2.0/publish/

Comment: Just wanted to mention that [warp](https://github.com/dgiagio/warp) is a tool similar to ILMerge that can create "self-contained single binary applications" with dotnet core apps.

Comment: It'll also turn what should have been a 135kb cli tool into a 35MB cli tool

Comment: Is there something like `dotnet publish -r current -c release`? I would like to publish executable for the current OS, and perhaps add that to csproj. It is much easier to call executable than rely on dotnet CLI to call a dll

Comment: Note: [From the CoreRT team](https://github.com/dotnet/corert/blob/master/README.md): "This project [CoreRT] is [superseded by NativeAOT](https://github.com/dotnet/runtimelab/tree/feature/NativeAOT/samples/HelloWorld#add-nativeaot-to-your-project) experiment in dotnet/runtimelab repo"

Answer (score 16):

**Before .NET Core 3.0**

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release --self-contained
```

**Pretty self explanatory:**

- Publish the project from the current directory.
- Build the project to run on Windows 64 bit machines.
- Build in release configuration mode
- Publish everything as “self-contained” so that everything required to
  run the app is packaged up with our executable

So this works right, we end up with a folder that has our exe and everything that is    required to run it, but the issue is that there is a tonne required to run even a HelloWorld console app.

[image: Publish folder]

**After .NET Core 3.0**

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true
```

All this does is runs our publish command but tells it to package it within a single file. You’ll notice that we no longer specify the self-contained flag. That’s because it’s assumed that if you are packaging as a single exe, that you will want all it’s dependencies along with it. Makes sense.

[image: Publish folder]

A single tidy exe! When this is executed, the dependencies are extracted to a temporary directory and then everything is ran from there. It’s essentially a zip of our previous publish folder! I’ve had a few plays around with it and honestly, it just works. There is nothing more to say about it. It just works.

**File Size And Startup Cost**

- Keen eyes will notice something about the above screenshot. The file size. It’s over 70MB! That’s crazy for an application that does nothing but print Hello World to the screen! This is solved in Preview 6 of .NET Core 3.0 with a feature called IL Linker or Publish trimmer that omits DLL’s that aren’t used.
- The other issue you may find is that there is a slight startup cost when running the self contained executable for the first time. Because it needs to essentially unzip all dependencies to a temporary directory on first run, that’s going to take a little bit of time to complete. It’s not crazy (5 seconds or so), but it’s noticeable. Luckily on subsequent runs it uses this already unzipped temp folder and so startup is immediate.

Modify the csproj and add PublishTrimmed = true.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>

    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>

    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>

    <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>

  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Now run the below command:

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true
```

**Reference**:

1. https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/06/20/publishing-a-single-exe-file-in-net-core-3-0/
2. https://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakingATinyNETCore30EntirelySelfcontainedSingleExecutable.aspx

Comment: win-x64 is hard-coded. I with there was an "auto" to publish for the current OS, whatever it is used to build

Comment: It may also be useful to reference the [original design document for single-file publishing](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/master/accepted/2020/single-file/design_3_0.md), which remains the closest I can find to official documentation from Microsoft, but doesn't appear to be indexed by Google and is thus difficult to find if you don't know where to look for it.

Answer (score 2):

[This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli#simpleSelf) from Microsoft uses the same `dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x64` that you have used, and documents it as follows (emphasis added):

> This creates a Release (rather than a Debug) version of your app for each target platform. **The resulting files are placed in a
>   subdirectory named publish** that's in a subdirectory of your project's
>   .\bin\Release\netcoreapp1.1 subdirectory. **Note
>   that each subdirectory contains the complete set of files (both your
>   app files and all .NET Core files) needed to launch your app.**
>
> Along with your application's files, the publishing process emits a
>   program database (.pdb) file that contains debugging information about
>   your app. The file is useful primarily for debugging exceptions. You
>   can choose not to package it with your application's files. You
>   should, however, save it in the event that you want to debug the
>   Release build of your app.

So the correct files to deploy are the ones in the `publish` subdirectory. That directory is 60+ MB because it includes the .NET core libraries needed for self-contained deployment.