# .NET Core - how does the 'dotnet publish' command work?

Tags: deployment, build, .net-core

I have a solution with some projects targeting .NET Standard 2.0 and a console application project targeting .NET Core 2.1.

I set "myFolder" as the output folder.
Building from Visual Studio, I get all DLL files in:

- "myFolder\netstandard2.0"
- "myFolder\netcoreapp2.1"

I get the same using the "dotnet build" command.
Now I need my console application's EXE file.
So I use the "dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64 MySolution.sln" command.

Now I get this new directory, "myFolder\netcoreapp2.1\win-x64", where I find all DLL files and the console application's EXE file.

Not enough!

I find one directory more, "myFolder\netcoreapp2.1\win-x64\publish", where I find again all DLL files and the console application's EXE file.

Which meaning do they have? I read the [command documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore21), but I didn't find my answer.

Comment: With .NET CORE 3.0 this is simplified, Checkout this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56710981/6441150

Comment: There being a copy of the files inside and outside the publish folder still happens in .NET5

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Per the documentation

> `-o|--output <OUTPUT_DIRECTORY>`
>
> Specifies the path for the output directory. If not specified, it defaults to ./bin/[configuration]/[framework]/publish/ for a framework-dependent deployment or ./bin/[configuration]/[framework]/[runtime]/publish/ for a self-contained deployment.

`dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64 --output ./MyTargetFolder MySolution.sln`

Comment: thank you for this. I couldn't find it anywhere else

Answer (score 12):

All you really need to understand to be able to successfully publish and deploy is that you need to `dotnet publish` and ensure that you have a Release configuration `-c Release`, as well as any other required options on the command line.

All of your files will be in the 'publish' subfolder, e.g. *./bin/Release/[framework that your solution is targeting]/publish*. The files contained here are everything that is needed for a running instance of your application/service. The `MySolution.dll` is the entry point for your app/service, and will automatically link to all of the other dependencies and configuration stored in the publish folder.

To configure and deploy a running instance, you need to work out how to deploy all of those files to a server, and somehow configure something (e.g. a web server, runtime, service host ...) to call your `MySolution.dll`.

Note that in your `dotnet publish` you're specifying `-r`, which means that your application is targetted to run under 64 bit Windows, as opposed to a Linux distribution or OS X (which makes it less portable, but it has the advantage of isolating your application from changes to an installed runtime on a server that you deploy it to.). That's why you're seeing an extra folder `win-x64`.

Also you're explicitly building from the solution configuration specified by your solution file `MySolution.sln`, which is probably the most reliable thing to do as this will ensure that any projects used as dependencies by your solution (which is a typical good practice) will be included in the build/publish.

Comment: I think something that puzzled original poster (and currently has me puzzled) is that the publish command creates a folder with all the dlls, plus within that three folders (properties, publish, runtimes) and that inner publish folder has all the dlls again. That's a little confusing!