# Publish all .net core projects in a directory

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, powershell, .net-core

I have a main directory containing all of my various .NET core solutions in subdirectories under it. Is there a way for me to publish all of these projects at once instead of opening and publishing each separately in Visual Studio?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET Core - how does the 'dotnet publish' command work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52421644/net-core-how-does-the-dotnet-publish-command-work)

Comment: No. My question is more specific. That question asks generally how dotnet publish works. My question asks how to recursively publish multiple projects, possibly in different unrelated solutions, grouped in a single location. E.g. AllOfMyCSharpProjects/Project1Folder, AllOfMyCSharpProjects/Project2Folder, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the [dotnet command line interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/).

To do this, open a PowerShell terminal and cd into the root directory containing the various projects you want to publish. From there, run the following:

```
$paths = Get-ChildItem -include *.csproj -Recurse
foreach($pathobject in $paths)
{
     cd $pathobject.directory.fullName
     dotnet publish
}
```

Doing this will publish every project into its default publish location, e.g. MyProjectFolder/bin/debug/netcoreapp3.1/publish.

To publish each project to a specified subdirectory, you can use the -o flag on the publish command. E.g. in the above, substitute `dotnet publish -o bin\Debug\myCustomPublishFolder` for `dotnet publish`