# Is that possible to publish ASP.Net Core 3.1 web application as a Single File

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.1

I know that we are able to publish .Net Core 3.x console applications as a `self-contained`, `singlefile`. But is it possible to publish web application as a single file?

I tried to use

```
<RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
<SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
<PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
<PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
```

But after publishing I've got the error `ANCM Application DLL Not Found`. My application is on `.Net Core 3.1.1`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried publishing asp.net as self contained deployment, which will put all the dependency file for run time into one folder. Then using command line in this folder run `dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true`

Comment: @Clint As I mentioned, I've set `<SelfContained>true</SelfContained>`. But is it important to publish it on command line instead of Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: @Clint I also did it but still getting same error.

Comment: To address your question to @Clint, and as discussed on a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50703578/publish-net-core-app-as-portable-executable), you should only need _either_ `<PublishSingleFile />` _or_ `/p:PublishSingleFile=true`; as you suspected, those are redundant. Note that you _shouldn't_ require the `<SelfContained />` element, as that's implied by `<PublishSingleFile />`—though I also don't think it will hurt anything.

Comment: I should also note that the [original design document for single file publishing](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/master/accepted/2020/single-file/design_3_0.md) may be a useful reference here. I bring this up because most references to this document point to the old location, so it's currently difficult to find if you don't know where to look.

Comment: @JeremyCaney Thank you for your help. I made your changes and I just got this error `HTTP Error 500.38 - ANCM Application DLL Not Found`

Answer (score 0):

You should edit your webconfig to look like

```
 <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
```

instead of

```
 <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
```